# How can I convert a UTC time string to the correct moment.js object in my local timezone?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following string that I implicitly know is in UTC timezone: `2008-03-09 18:02:29`

How can I use moment.js to convert it to an object in my local timezone?

I tried the following but it doesn't adjust the time for my local timezone:

```
> moment("2008-03-09 18:02:29 UTC").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss zz')
"2008-03-09 18:02:29"
```

PS. I live near Washington DC (UTC -4). But this needs to work properly for any user from anywhere in the world.

I can do it without moment.js like this (but it only works in Chrome, not FF):

```
new Date('2008-03-09 18:02:29 UTC');
```

So what's the moment.js code analogous to this??

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220467/how-to-convert-moment-js-date-to-users-local-timezone?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that you have a UTC date, so you are going to want to parse in UTC mode. After that, use Moment's `.local()` function to get back to the time of the current user.

```
moment.utc('2008-03-09 18:02:29').local().format()
"2008-03-09T13:02:29-05:00"
```

I am in -5, and as you can see, the date was pushed back five hours.

Comment: Maggie Pint has the correct answer it seems. But note that the result can be surprising. I live in Switzerland and we changed to daylight saving time last Sunday (March 27th), so we live now in UTC+2. But the result of Maggie’s code on my computer is `2008-03-09T19:02:29+01:00`. But this is correct, because at this date we were in UTC+1.

Answer (score 0):

With moment timezone

```
moment("2008-03-09 18:02:29 UTC").tz('America/New_York'); // => EST
```

Comment: FYI, I live in Washington, but someone else who accesses this website may live anywhere in the world. How do I make it convert to the local time for that browser?? (Sorry if I was unclear in the original question). I'm looking for something analogous to `new Date('2008-03-09 18:02:29 UTC');`