# Display and format a UTC date to my timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, formatting

I have a string representing a UTC date:

`'2016-07-29T01:33:56.72'`

I would like to display this date corrected to my timezone and nicely formatted:

`'2016-07-28 22:33:56'`

I tried libraries like `moment.js` or `numeral.js` but I still didn't found a clear way to do it. My problem so far is that I am starting with a string object and not a Date object.

Comment: Answered here for moment.js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220467/how-to-convert-moment-js-date-to-users-local-timezone

Comment: oh wow thanks, didn't see that, do you want to add the answer

Comment: There are many approaches, but likely the simplest is to parse the string to a Date, then create a [*formatted string*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript). A date library can help (e.g. [*Fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) is small and does parsing and formatting), but you really only need about 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here for moment.js: [How to convert Moment.js date to users local timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220467/)… – Voyta